# How to set Pipeline 'Task version' in YAML in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-yaml

How can I set this value in YAML? This is from Azure devops pipeline
[image]

EDIT: There is a powershell version below the same UI(Preferred PowerShell Version), the question is not about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is set in "@4"

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set it as,

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: FilePath'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure Demo'
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: 1.0.0
```

However you should be able to see the relevant YAML code by clicking on the YAML

[image]

Comment: Why not? i just did that

Comment: In release pipeline you cannot

Comment: i just did in release pipeline, it does not matter which pipeline you are in

Comment: I cannot see it in both release and build pipeline :)

Comment: check the image attached

Comment: In mobile version of stack overflow I cannot see image

Comment: You gave the wrong answer. PreferredAzurePowerShellVersion is below the 'Task Version'. The question is about 'Task Version'

Comment: in your attached image 'Task version is 4.*'